# How to get Bootstrap Popover height?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking a way for find Popover height. I only able to find width

I need to find out popover height as I will resize DIV height based on Popover height.

Note: Bootstrap 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `css("height)"` or even `.height()`:

```
$("#popoverId").height()
```

[For example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers):

```
$(".popover:eq(4)").height()
```

(click on the <kbd>Popover on top</kbd> button and then run the code above in the browser console)